# if the reply is more than 1 why do not react

Tags: c++

why not work if more than one answer key:

*can not use the key*

> if (resp == **'open'**)

*but if I replace it with one letter only, then he can work*

> if (resp == **'y'**)

*or replace it with the number, then he can work*

> if (resp == **1**)

I wish she could write more than one letter

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char resp;
    index:
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"just an example of course"<<endl;
    cout<<"type {open} to return to the index\n";
    cin>>resp;
    if (resp == 'open'){
        goto index;
    }
    else if(resp == 2)
        {
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }



}
```

Comment: '1' not the same as 1 and '2' not the same as 2/

Comment: you are using `char resp;` which can hold only one char value. So you can not compare `(resp == 'open')` . Only single character you can compare here.

Comment: Whoa there. Goto? Arrgghhh my eyes!!!

Comment: You should compile with debug info and all warnings. With `g++ -Wall -g` you would have get a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resp` is of type char so it can only store one character.

1. You can create the object of string and then directly compare it.
   Change `char resp` to `string resp` and then you can use `if(resp=="open")`

Here is your code with edits:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string resp; //Fix 1
    int jawab;
    index:
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"just an example of course"<<endl;
    cout<<"type {open} to return to the index\n";
    cin>>resp;
    if (resp =="open"){ //Fix 2
        goto index;
    }
    else if(jawab == 2)
    {
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: replace `char` with `std::string` to store more characters. C-style arrays are more difficult to use correctly.

Comment: @Ani : briliant, this is very helpful

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Thanks for the suggestion, I have incorporated it in the  code.

Comment: `cin >> resp` in example 2 is bad, if the person types more than 9 characters then it will cause a buffer overflow. If using a char array then you must use a different input function to have safe code.   Also, using `goto` instead of a loop is an awful idea.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I agree with you. `char resp[10]` is just an example. I could have used `char resp[256]`.
I have not changed `goto` because OP might be learning how to use `goto`.

Comment: `char resp[256]` is still bad, the person could type in 256 characters.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I agree with you. However this is just an example.

Comment: @Ani an example of how to write buffer overflows? I can't upvote such a thing.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Removed the bad example :)

Answer (score 4):

use `string` instead of `char`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string resp;
index:
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"just an example of course"<<endl;
    cout<<"type {open} to return to the index\n";
    cin >> resp;
    if (resp == "open"){
        goto index;
    }
    /*
    else if(jawab == 2)
        {
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`resp` is a character instead of a character array. Also, if you want to test if two strings are the same, use `strcmp(a,b)==0` instead.

Also, you should use `"open"` instead of `'open'`. Single quotes are used for characters, while double quotes refer to strings.

Answer (score 0):

I am not for sure that what is your requirement. If you want to compare two characters, you can do it in this way:

```
char resp;

if (resp == 'o'){...}
```

But if you want to compare two strings, you should:

```
std:string resp;

if (resp.compare("open") == 0){...}
```